# OpenTelemetry K8s Operator Collector - Exporter Configuration for Prometheus

Tags: azure, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, aks

I have some container workloads in Azure AKS cluster. I need to use OpenTelemetry to get the metrics, logs and trace data from the container workload and get it collected by the OTEL collector.

I have setup Grafana and Prometheus server in the form of K8s containers as well in the AKS cluster. When I deploy the OTEL collector in the form of a deployment-pod (https://opentelemetry.io/docs/kubernetes/helm/collector/) the below is the exporter configuration for pointing the data from OTEL collector to prometheus data source:

```
exporters:
  prometheus:
    enable_open_metrics: true
    endpoint: ${env.MY_POD_IP}:9464
    resource_to_telemetry_conversion:
      enabled: true

receivers:
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
      - job_name: opentelemetry-collector
        scrape_interval: 10s
        static_configs:
        - targets:
          - ${env:MY_POD_IP}:8888
```

This works. Here the OTEL collector is able to export the data to the Prometheus data source and it can be visualised using Grafana.

However, my painpoint is when using the OpenTelemetry Collector as a Kubernetes Operator (https://opentelemetry.io/docs/kubernetes/operator/). Where do I define the exporter and receiver configuration?

Below is the YAML configuration for the OTEL collector:

```
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: otel-collector
spec:
  config: |
    receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
          http:
    processors:
      memory_limiter:
        check_interval: 1s
        limit_percentage: 75
        spike_limit_percentage: 15
      batch:
        send_batch_size: 10000
        timeout: 10s

    exporters:
      debug:

    service:
      pipelines:
        traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: []
          exporters: [debug]
```

Here, how do I define that the data needs to be exported to the Prometheus server endpoint? I assume that port 9464 needs to be used. However, where do I mention that configuration?